# Questions concering the integral $F(\lambda)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{\lambda x}}dl(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, solution-verification, continuity

I have 4 questions concerning the following integral:

$\forall \lambda >0$ we have:

$$F(\lambda)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{\lambda x}}dx $$

I would like to have some help to find an answer concerning question 1 & 4 and to know if my solution at question 2 & 3 is correct for all the cases.

**->Any help on just one of this question will be very nice<-**

Please don't delete/erase this question, since it took me quite some time to write it. :-)

1. Prove that $F(\lambda)$ is continuous on $]0; \infty[$.

-Did not succeed to find a convincing proof, indeed it is easy to prove that $F(\lambda)$ is defined on $]0; \infty[$ as it is finite but how to prove the continuity? (in the simplest way possible).

2. Let $(u_n) \in ]0; \infty[$ an increasing function s.t. $u_n \underset{n \to \infty }{\rightarrow} \infty $. Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(u_n)$

-It is easy to show that $F(\lambda)$ is positive decreasing function.

Moreover we we have that $f_{\lambda}(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{\lambda x}} = \frac{\sqrt{x^4}}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{\lambda x}} \leq \frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{\lambda x}}=\frac{1}{e^{\lambda x}}=g(x)$

Hence $f_{u_n}(x)$ is bounded by $g(x)$ and because $f_{u_n}(x)$ is a continuous mapping we can writte $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{u_n}(x) = 0$.
So by the DCT we get that: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{u_n x}}dl(x)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{u_n x}}dl(x) =0 $$

3. Let $(v_n) \in ]0; \infty[$  be a decreasing function s.t. $v_n \underset{n \to \infty }{\rightarrow} 0 $. Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(v_n)$
   -As $ v_{n+1} \leq v_n \Rightarrow e^{v_{n+1}} \leq e^{v_n} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{e^{v_n}} \leq \frac{1}{e^{v_{n+1}}} \Rightarrow f_{v_n}(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{v_n x}} \leq f_{v_{n+1}}(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{v_{n+1} x}} $

Now because $f_{v_n}(x)$ is continuous $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{v_n}(x)= f_{\lim_{n \to \infty} v_n}(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} $. Hence by the MCT we have:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{v_n x}}dl(x)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}e^{v_n x}}dl(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dl(x) = \infty $$

4. Prove that the limit $\lim_{\lambda \to 0^+} \lambda F(\lambda)$ exists and find it.

-Did not succeed to find a convincing answer.

Thank you

Comment: What is your $dl(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $F(\lambda)$ be represented as the Laplace Transform

$$F(\lambda)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$$

We will show direclty that $F$ is continuous for $\lambda\in(0,\infty)$.

Let $\lambda_0\in (0,\infty)$ and select $\lambda$ such that $|\lambda-\lambda_0|\le \lambda_0/2$.  Then, we have for any given $\varepsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}
|F(\lambda)-F(\lambda_0)|&=\left|\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}\left(e^{-\lambda x}-e^{-\lambda_0 x}\right)\,dx\right| \\\\
&\le \int_0^\infty \left|e^{-\lambda x}-e^{-\lambda_0 x}\right|\,dx\\\\
&=\left|\frac1{\lambda}-\frac1{\lambda_0}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{\lambda-\lambda_0}{\lambda\lambda_0}\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{2|\lambda - \lambda_0|}{\lambda_0^2} \\\\
&<\varepsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|\lambda-\lambda_0|< \min\left(\lambda_0/2,\lambda_0^2\varepsilon /2 \right)$.  And we are done!

---

Next, we shall prove that $\lim_{\lambda\to 0^+}\lambda F(\lambda)=1$.

To begin, we can write for any $x_0>0$

$$\begin{align}
|\lambda F(\lambda)-1|&=\int_0^\infty  \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{x_0}  \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}\right)\,dx\\\\
&+\int_{x_0}^\infty  \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}\right)\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

For the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$, we have the simple estimates

$$\begin{align}
0&<\int_{x_0}^\infty  \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}\right)\,dx\\\\
&\le \frac{e^{-\lambda x_0}}{x_0^4}
\end{align}$$

We can choose an $x_0$ so large to make the integral arbitrarily small.

For this fixed $x_0$, the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ can be made arbitraryily small by choosing $\lambda$ small enough.  I'll leave the formal delta-epsilon proof to the reader.

And we are done!

Comment: Thank you for your time. Concerning question 4/ have you an idea on how to proceed? And did my other answers are correct.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I am looking at the fourth problem now.

Answer (score 2):

While already answered, here is a slightly different solution with the following interpretation of the convoluted questions. Essentially it is asked:

1. Show continuity of $F(\lambda)$ on $(0,\infty)$
2. Check the limit $\lambda \to \infty$
3. Check the limit $\lambda \to 0^+$
4. Check the limit $\lambda \to 0^+$ of $\lambda F(\lambda)$

The third one follows from the fourth, once the limit is known to be finite.

1. Here it is easiest to use the definition of continuity. Fix $\lambda_0 >0$ and pick any $\epsilon > 0$. Then let $\delta=\frac{\lambda_0^2\epsilon}{1+\lambda_0 \epsilon}$ and so for all $|\lambda-\lambda_0|<\delta$, we have $\lambda \geq \frac{\lambda_0}{1+\lambda_0\epsilon}$ and
   $$|F(\lambda)-F(\lambda_0)| \leq \frac{|\lambda-\lambda_0|}{\lambda \lambda_0} < \frac{1+\lambda_0 \epsilon}{\lambda_0^2} \cdot \frac{\lambda_0^2\epsilon}{1+\lambda_0 \epsilon} = \epsilon \, .$$
2. $$0 \leq F(\lambda)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} \,e^{-\lambda x}\,{\rm d}x \leq \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} \, {\rm d}x = \frac1\lambda$$ by which the limit follows.

3 + 4. For all $\lambda>0$: $$0\leq \lambda F(\lambda)=\lambda\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} \,e^{-\lambda x}\,{\rm d}x \stackrel{u=\lambda x}{=} \int_0^\infty \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{u^4+\lambda^4}} \,e^{-u}\,{\rm d}u \leq \int_0^\infty e^{-u} \, {\rm d}u = 1 \, .$$
Thus, by the DCT, $$\lim_{\lambda \to 0} \lambda F(\lambda) = \int_0^\infty \lim_{\lambda \to 0}\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{u^4+\lambda^4}} \,e^{-u}\,{\rm d}u = \int_0^\infty e^{-u} \, {\rm d}u =1 \, .$$

Comment: (+1) Well done.